# How would i check if the returned object is null in gson

Tags: java, api, gson, minecraft

i am making a minecraft plugin in java and i am trying to check if the api gives a null key value.

I have tried object.isJsonNull but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

```
try {
                    URL hypixel = new URL("https://api.hypixel.net/player?key=bd04adbb-7afc-42da-a833-09dbf09fbf06&name=" + username);
                    URLConnection urlConn = hypixel.openConnection();
                    urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
                    urlConn.getDoOutput();


                    if(args[0].equals("getxp")) {


                    try(final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()))) {
                        final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

                        final JsonObject object = parser.parse(reader.readLine()).getAsJsonObject();



                        String exp = object.getAsJsonObject("player").get("networkExp").getAsString();

                        if(object.isJsonNull()) {
                            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player does not exist!");
                        }

                        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "EXP: " + exp);

                    }
                    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

This is the response i get from the api

```
{"success":true,"player":null}
```

Comment: Are you expecting your null test to work when you do it after you already tried to call a method on it?

Answer (score 0):

Use .has(String) and .isNull(String)

A conservative usage could be;

```
if (object.has("my_object_name") && !object.isNull("my_object_name")) {
    // Do something with object.
  }
```